# Big cartel centering an image

Tags: bigcartel

Hi I am using the luna theme for my big cartel website and used a HTML code to put an image on the homepage but it is showing on the left instead of the centre of the page.

I have looked for HTML codes to try and centre it but am unable to find any?

Also if anyone knows HTML codes to put text on the homepage too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the homepage logo that you move?

To add text on homepage, go on layout code, select where you want to add some text, and use the balise `<p>text here</p>` or `<h1>bigger text here</h1>`, that depends on the size of text you want.

Do I answer to your question?